# Compiling with -fno-automatic still produces a stack overflow error

Tags: compilation, segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I'm calling some Fortran code from Julia and am getting a stack overflow error.

From what I can see in the gfortran man page, when using the `-fno-automatic` flag, the stack is never used however I'm still getting a stack overflow. Interestingly, if I compile on a Mac (rather than Linux) I don't get this stack overflow.

I've also tried setting `ulimit -s` in the shell to no avail, any further ideas to debug would be greatly appreciated!

**Mac gfortran version**

```bash
 $ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/12/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin22
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc --libdir=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-12 --with-gmp=/opt/homebrew/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/opt/homebrew/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/opt/homebrew/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/opt/homebrew/opt/isl --with-zstd=/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 12.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --with-system-zlib --build=aarch64-apple-darwin22 --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0)
```

**Linux gfortran version**

```bash
 $ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

**Compiler commands**

```bash
gfortran -J./src -fsyntax-only -c -ffree-line-length-300 src/module_1.f90
gfortran -J./src  -fsyntax-only -c -ffree-line-length-300 src/module_2.f90 
gfortran -J./src  -fsyntax-only -c -ffree-line-length-300 src/module_3.f90 
gfortran -J./src  -fsyntax-only -c -ffree-line-length-300 src/module_4.f90 
gfortran -shared -fPIC -ffree-line-length-300 -g -fbounds-check -Wall -Wno-tabs ./src/file1.f90 ./src/file2.f90 ./src/file3.f90 ./src/file4.f90 ./src/file5.f90 ./src/file6.f90 -o shared_object_file.so
```

**Error message (originates from Julia)**

```
┌ Error: ERROR: 
│   exception =
│    StackOverflowError:
```

**An update**

An update, I'm note sure it's a stack overflow issue after running the code via gdb. I can see that when a subroutine (passed to `subroutine1` as argument `f`) is called it instantly segfaults:

```
Thread 1 "julia" hit Breakpoint 1, module1::subroutine1 (m1=0, m2=11, n1=1, n2=66, n=66, id=..., 
f=0x1554b2c4de9c, j=0x1554b2c4de80, max_iter=100, x=..., y=..., tol=1e-08, iflag=.TRUE.) at ./src/solve_model.f90:261
261         do k=1, max_iter
(gdb) step
262             call F()
(gdb) step
Thread 1 "julia" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00001554b2c4de9c in ?? ()
```

It appears that subroutine `f` isn't entered, just the call to it causes the segfault.

Below is an example of `subroutine1`:

```
subroutine subroutine1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, F, J, arg9, arg10)
    implicit none
    interface           
        subroutine F(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
            use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: int64
            integer(int64), intent(in) :: arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6(arg5)
            double precision, intent(inout)::arg9(arg1:arg2, arg3:arg4)
            double precision, intent(out):: arg10(arg1:arg2, arg5), y(arg1:arg2, arg3:arg4)
        end subroutine
```

Comment: Could you post the error message(s)?

Comment: Why do you think `-fno-automatic` implies stack is never used?

Comment: @francescalus from the gfortran docs: “Use -fno-automatic to never use the stack” https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html

Comment: *"Treat each program unit (except those marked as RECURSIVE"* In Fortran 2018 all procedures are recursive by default. Try marking them as `non_recursive` and explore compiler options that can do that.

Comment: Also, if you use OpenMP or other threading, that also implies recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @VladimirFГероямслава, do you have any examples of adding this non_recursive flag? Also, any reason you think this would occur on Linux but not Mac, when using identical compilers (gfortran) and compiler options?

Comment: Are they identical versions of the compiler? What does `gfortran -version` tell you in each case? What other flags do you have on the compile line? Can you please show us the full compile and link lines, and error messages and the output of gfortran --version - edit the question to do this, *not* in a comment.

Comment: Who knows, we need the full details, as requested by Ian and preferably a [mcve]. Tje `non_recursive` attribute is used in the aource code the same way as the `recursive` one. Search yourself for ways how to do it using compiler flags instead of the source code. The opposite flag is `-frecursive`.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirFГероямслава and Ian, please see the edits. I apologise for the (probably) subpar compiling commands, I'm relatively new to compiled languages like Fortran and makefiles.

 I firstly compile the required modules and then created a shared library, which is then loaded in Julia: 

[Lidbl](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Libdl/)


Unfortunately, the error message produced by Julia as you can see is very light on details and just points towards a StackOverflowError, without a specific line number.

Comment: Another note, this stackoverflow error only occurs when a specific call is made with a subroutine, everything else functions correctly. So I’m not sure if it’s a compiler issue?

Comment: My understanding of `-fno-automatic` is that it won't prevent the allocation of arrays on the stack, if the size of these arrays is not known at compile time. I would try instead `-fno-stack-arrays`, which (I guess) will force the allocation of arrays on the heap instead of on the stack.

Comment: Yes, my understanding of that flag is that it moves the data to the static segment and does not use the stack for local variables. That is only possible for scalars and constant sized arrays.

Comment: Have you tried `-fno-stack-arrays`? Regarding your update, it doesn't eliminate the stack overflow hypothesis (a stack overflow can result in a segmentation violation).

Comment: @PierU, I've tried `-fno-stack-arrays` and that unfortunately still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I understand that `subroutine1()` is a Fortran routine. If the actual routine that you are passing to the dummy `f` also a Fortran routine? Could you show the interfaces of these routines?

Comment: @PierU, correct the dummy argument `f` also represents a subroutine within the same module (`module1`) that `subroutine1` is contained in. I'll add an example of what the `f` interface looks like above.